# Why is it always raining in Blade Runner universe (Los Angeles)?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-runner, blade-runner-2049

Is there any explanation or background information that connects climate related changes with the timeline in *Blade Runner*?

There have been sprinkled info related to nuclear war, massive solar farms (2049), dead trees, etc.

Is there something I can read to know more about this movie's universe with regards to its climate?